# Google Maps Marker giving a null reference on Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

i need help with adding a Google Maps Marker on my map. i want the map to show the current location of my mobile device and i want it to show the location using a Marker.

Now the problem that i have is that the code for displaying the current location of my device is exactly the same one I used before on another project and it works there with no problems, but when I use it here, it gives me problems.

here is my code below and the information from the Logcat.

**code:**

```
private void displayLocation() {
    try
    {
        // check if permission are granted
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            return;
        }
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if(mLastLocation != null)
        {

            final double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            final double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

            // update to the firebase database
            geoFire.setLocation(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(), new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener(){
                @Override
                public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                    // add marker to the map
                    if(mUserMarker != null)
                    {
                        mUserMarker.remove(); // removes the already existing marker
                    }

                    mUserMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude))
                            .title("You are here"));
                    // move the map camera to the current location of the user
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude,longitude),15.0f));

                }
            });
            Log.d("location Updates",String.format("Your location was changed :%f/%f",latitude,longitude));

        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("Location Error","Cannot get your current location");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

**Logcat:**

```
12-22 05:00:53.580 32403-32603/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser V/FA: Session started, time: 16168691
12-22 05:00:53.580 32403-32603/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/FA: Logging event (FE): session_start(_s), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=1529463756370892487}]
12-22 05:00:53.590 32403-32603/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser V/FA: Using measurement service
12-22 05:00:53.590 32403-32603/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser V/FA: Connecting to remote service
12-22 05:00:53.600 32403-32603/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/FA: Connected to remote service
12-22 05:00:53.600 32403-32603/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
12-22 05:00:55.850 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
12-22 05:00:55.960 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
12-22 05:00:55.970 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
12-22 05:00:56.000 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser E/Qmage: isQIO : stream is not a QIO file
12-22 05:00:56.000 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
12-22 05:00:56.030 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{cb08adf V.E...... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
12-22 05:00:56.070 32403-32656/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [878x327]-format:1
12-22 05:00:56.080 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
12-22 05:00:56.110 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
12-22 05:00:56.140 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
12-22 05:00:57.400 32403-32419/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( KHgHwTAdSvWBqpmiJwuyZGCoTy62 ).
12-22 05:00:57.400 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
12-22 05:00:57.400 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/FirebaseApp: Notified 1 auth state listeners.
12-22 05:00:57.420 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
12-22 05:00:57.430 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser time:16172541
12-22 05:00:57.460 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
12-22 05:00:57.460 32403-32603/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 13826
12-22 05:00:57.460 32403-32603/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser V/FA: Activity paused, time: 16172571
12-22 05:00:57.460 32403-32603/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=13826, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=1529463756370892487}]
12-22 05:00:57.500 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser V/FA: onActivityCreated
12-22 05:00:57.660 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/zzbx: Making Creator dynamically
12-22 05:00:57.740 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser W/ResourcesManager: Resource getTopLevelResources for package com.google.android.gmsoverlayDirs =Null
12-22 05:00:57.820 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 11020000
12-22 05:00:57.830 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 11951440
12-22 05:00:58.230 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser E/Qmage: isQIO : stream is not a QIO file
12-22 05:00:58.240 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
12-22 05:00:58.240 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@7d123cb
12-22 05:00:58.250 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@6f647a8
12-22 05:00:58.250 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@6f647a8
12-22 05:00:58.300 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser W/System.err: mkdir failed: EEXIST (File exists) : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser/cache/debug
12-22 05:00:58.300 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser W/System.err: mkdir failed: EEXIST (File exists) : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser/cache
12-22 05:00:58.310 32403-969/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-22 05:00:58.320 32403-969/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-22 05:00:58.350 32403-969/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 89 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 32403, getuid(): 10197
12-22 05:00:58.400 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
12-22 05:00:58.410 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
12-22 05:00:58.540 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
12-22 05:00:58.540 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
12-22 05:00:58.550 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
12-22 05:00:58.550 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
12-22 05:00:58.600 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/Location Error: Cannot get your current location
12-22 05:00:58.600 32403-32603/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 16173714
12-22 05:00:58.600 32403-32603/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=MainActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=1529463756370892487, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Home, firebase_screen_id(_si)=1529463756370892488}]
12-22 05:00:58.610 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
12-22 05:00:58.610 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{e53d5b2 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
12-22 05:00:58.610 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/Choreographer: Skipped 67 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-22 05:00:58.670 32403-32656/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
12-22 05:00:58.680 32403-969/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 108 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 32403, getuid(): 10197
12-22 05:00:58.720 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
12-22 05:00:58.750 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
12-22 05:00:58.760 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
12-22 05:00:58.770 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
12-22 05:00:58.780 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
12-22 05:00:58.790 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
12-22 05:00:58.790 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
12-22 05:00:58.810 32403-992/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7f89604ea8
12-22 05:00:58.820 32403-992/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x1773]-format:2
12-22 05:00:58.850 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
12-22 05:00:58.860 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
12-22 05:00:58.950 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/location Updates: Your location was changed :-24,721872/31,223932
12-22 05:00:58.960 32403-969/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 89
12-22 05:00:58.970 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/location Updates: Your location was changed :-24,721872/31,223932
12-22 05:00:58.980 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@c5af6d7 time:16174090
12-22 05:00:58.990 32403-970/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-22 05:00:59.000 32403-970/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-22 05:00:59.000 32403-970/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 89 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 32403, getuid(): 10197
12-22 05:00:59.010 32403-972/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-22 05:00:59.010 32403-972/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-22 05:00:59.020 32403-971/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-22 05:00:59.020 32403-971/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-22 05:00:59.020 32403-972/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 60 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 32403, getuid(): 10197
12-22 05:00:59.020 32403-971/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 59 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 32403, getuid(): 10197
12-22 05:00:59.030 32403-969/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-22 05:00:59.030 32403-969/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-22 05:00:59.030 32403-969/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 77 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 32403, getuid(): 10197
12-22 05:00:59.100 32403-971/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 114 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 32403, getuid(): 10197
12-22 05:00:59.110 32403-972/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 51 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 32403, getuid(): 10197
12-22 05:00:59.110 32403-32656/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7f960f9f08
12-22 05:00:59.120 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
12-22 05:00:59.130 32403-969/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 47 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 32403, getuid(): 10197
12-22 05:00:59.170 32403-32656/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7f960f9f08
12-22 05:00:59.210 32403-32656/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7f960f9f08
12-22 05:00:59.240 32403-970/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 89
12-22 05:00:59.240 32403-970/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-22 05:00:59.240 32403-970/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-22 05:00:59.240 32403-970/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 89 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 32403, getuid(): 10197
12-22 05:00:59.260 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-22 05:00:59.260 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                                 at bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser.Home$1.onComplete(Home.java:166)
                                                                                                                 at com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire$2.onComplete(GeoFire.java:175)
                                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.rr.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7407)
                                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
12-22 05:00:59.260 32403-32603/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/FA: Logging event (FE): app_exception(_ae), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=crash, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Home, firebase_screen_id(_si)=1529463756370892488, timestamp=1513911659271, fatal=1}]
12-22 05:00:59.290 32403-32603/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 690
12-22 05:00:59.290 32403-32603/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=690, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Home, firebase_screen_id(_si)=1529463756370892488}]
12-22 05:00:59.410 32403-971/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 59
12-22 05:00:59.410 32403-971/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-22 05:00:59.410 32403-971/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-22 05:00:59.410 32403-971/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 59 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 32403, getuid(): 10197
12-22 05:00:59.430 32403-972/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 60
12-22 05:00:59.430 32403-972/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-22 05:00:59.430 32403-972/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-22 05:00:59.430 32403-972/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 60 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 32403, getuid(): 10197
12-22 05:00:59.490 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                          Process: bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser, PID: 32403
                                                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                              at bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser.Home$1.onComplete(Home.java:166)
                                                                                                              at com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire$2.onComplete(GeoFire.java:175)
                                                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.rr.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7407)
                                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
12-22 05:00:59.500 32403-1014/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/FirebaseCrash: Sending crashes
12-22 05:00:59.500 32403-1014/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-22 05:00:59.500 32403-1014/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-22 05:00:59.510 32403-969/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 77
12-22 05:00:59.530 32403-970/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 89
12-22 05:00:59.540 32403-969/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-22 05:00:59.540 32403-969/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-22 05:00:59.540 32403-969/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 77 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 32403, getuid(): 10197
12-22 05:00:59.550 32403-970/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-22 05:00:59.550 32403-970/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-22 05:00:59.550 32403-970/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 89 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 32403, getuid(): 10197
12-22 05:00:59.650 32403-971/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 59
12-22 05:00:59.660 32403-972/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 60
12-22 05:00:59.800 32403-970/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 89
12-22 05:00:59.860 32403-1014/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/FirebaseCrash: Response code: 200
12-22 05:00:59.860 32403-1014/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/FirebaseCrash: Report sent with crash report id: 769450ec1c000000
12-22 05:00:59.970 32403-969/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 77
12-22 05:01:00.390 32403-994/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
12-22 05:01:00.400 32403-994/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
12-22 05:01:00.400 32403-994/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
12-22 05:01:00.400 32403-994/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000004/n/arm64-v8a
12-22 05:01:00.400 32403-994/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser W/ResourcesManager: Resource getTopLevelResources for package com.google.android.gmsoverlayDirs =Null
12-22 05:01:01.510 32403-32403/bailphoneuser.com.hotdeskdigital.bailphone.bailphoneuser I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 32403 SIG: 9
```

I have been looking for a solution for a couple of days now but i have not succeeded. I am hoping I'll find help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the logcat output that you have provided, the first thing you need to address is the fact that your `mMap` variable is null.

My guess is that you're either calling `displayLocation()` before the `onMapReady(...)` callback has fired, or your class isn't equipped to handle the callback at all.

If you're using the Google Map Fragment, the basic approach is as follows:

In your `onCreate(...)` method:

`((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment)).getMapAsync(this);`

Make sure your class implements `com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback`.

Then, override the `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` method and set your `mMap` variable.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){

mMap = googleMap;

//Do whatever else you need to with the map...
}
```

Make sure you don't use `mMap` until it has been set, and you should be able to add your markers, and do other stuff without issue.

Comment: hi. i have implemented the override method 'OnMapReady'